# What files own my bad sectors?

Tags: hard-drive

I've just built a box using 14.04 (Trusty) and have had sectors go bad on my hard drive. I found out when I went to do the first backup! Terrible way to start the new year. I haven't noticed anything not working yet, but I'm sure I will, so... I will get a new hard drive and attempt to clone it using clonezilla.

What I need to figure out is what files (if any) these bad sectors contained. If they are system files then I guess I can reinstall them (or the probably the whole package). If they are data files then I can choose what to do.

Given the numbers of the bad sectors (183 of them according to Disks), how can I find what file names have been corrupted?

I really don't want to have to build this box all over again... it's taken me days to get everything "just right"

Happy New Year,

Comment: If the drive is still under warranty, ask them to ship you a new one, copy all the data over using `ddrescue` and then [dban](http://www.dban.org/) the broken drive and ship it back...

Comment: @Muzaffar, not really applicable here.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to try reading every file and see which ones give you errors.  Fake a `tar` backup and it should report any errors it has reading the files:

```
sudo tar -cf /dev/zero --one-file-system /
```

This will cause tar to back up all of your files but throw away the backup ( /dev/zero is a device psuedo file that returns as many zeros as you want to read, and throws away anything you write to it ).

On the other hand, this will put more wear and tear on the disk, possibly causing it to get worse, so instead you should just get another disk and make a *real* backup to it, then you can restore it when you get a replacement drive.